# Can I somehow opt out from sponsored tag link ads?

Tags: support, site-ads

Though I've opted out to see any ads in my profile settings

[image]

I still see "sponsored links for this tag"

[image]

I find that very annoying, and it slows loading of the main page a lot.

Is there any way to opt out that this is shown?

Comment: Stylus - `.js-zone-container { display: none;} `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot.

You also do not opt out of seeing *any* ads. The privilege is specifically for *reduced* ads, which hides the banner ads when viewing questions, per the [help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) on it.

We do not offer a way of opting out of any other ads on the site outside of using an ad blocker.

Comment: Well, ty. I'll try an ad blocker most probably.